# Native PHP function for hex string representation?

Tags: php

Is there a *native* PHP function for converting a string to its HEX representation that can be then `eval()`'d as a string, such as:

```
"ABC" => "\x41\x42\x43"
```

I know it can be done in several steps, I'm just wondering if I'm unnecessarily complicating something that could be done with a single, native function?

Comment: The closest you can get is with `bin2hex()`, then you'd have to add the `\x` to each character manually: `'\x' . implode( '\x', array_map( 'bin2hex', str_split( 'ABC'))));`

Comment: What do you mean by `eval()'d` if it is a `string`?

Comment: @arkascha I mean that `"\x41\x42\x43"` is valid PHP, and could be eval'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in PHP function to achieve the same results, but with some PHP-Fu you can do it in one line:

```
$str = 'ABC';
$str = '\x'.implode('\x', str_split(bin2hex($str), 2));
echo $str; // \x41\x42\x43
```

There is also a [piece of code in the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php#47663) which gives exactly the same results:

```
$str = 'ABC';
$field=bin2hex($str);
$field=chunk_split($field,2,"\\x");
$field= "\\x" . substr($field,0,-2);
echo $field; // \x41\x42\x43
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no native function, but you can use `hex2bin` to eval PHP code which is in hex, e.g.

```
eval(hex2bin("6563686f20706928293b")); # Output: 3.14159265359
eval(hex2bin(bin2hex("echo pi();")));  # Behind the scenes.
```

Or you can call the function which name is in hex string:

```
$ echo '<?$_=hex2bin(7069);die($_());' | php # 7069 = pi
3.14159265359
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the original question!

Comment: Hex representation that can be then [eval](http://php.net/eval)'d as a string? So can you clarify the question?

Comment: So the question is about 'function for converting', not how to eval a string? I think I do now.

Comment: I agree my question is somewhat confusing now that I read it, I meant something like `var_export()` but exporting the values as hex only!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
function strtohex($string) {
    if (!empty($string)) {
        $output = null;
        $count = strlen($string, "UTF-8");

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $output .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

For one-liners, the only alternative I can think about is the `bin2hex()` function, which is native in PHP and it offers the same.

Comment: I never said that my string was UTF-8, it can actually be binary! Also, your function does not return the format asked in the question. Finally, there's a bug in your code: if your string is UTF-8, `$string[$i]` will only return one byte. To retrieve one character from a UTF-8 string, you need to use `mb_substr()`.

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed it right now. I'm accustomed to write multibyte-aware code and I didn't checked this snippet well enough. Sorry about it

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 1234;
echo printf("%x", $n); //should return the hexadecimal format of the number
```

Comment: First off, `printf()` prints directly to output, so you don't need to echo its return value. Secondly, this is no way answers the question. OP is dealing with strings, not integers.

Comment: Yep, this is not answering the question!